# Pythonic way of removing one word entries from compound list

Tags: python, strings

Assume a multi-line file (`myInput.txt`) with lines comprising one or more words.

```
echo -e "Foo\nFoo bar\nFoo baz\nFoo bar baz\nBar\nBaz\nBaz qux\nBaz qux quux\nQux quux" > myInput.txt
```

I wish to remove all one-word lines that are identical with the first word of any multi-word lines **using Python**.

```
echo -e "Foo bar\nFoo baz\nFoo bar baz\nBar\nBaz qux\nBaz qux quux\nQux quux" > myGoal.txt
```

The following code satisfies my goal but does not appear overtly Pythonic to me.

```
from itertools import compress

myList = list()
with open("myInput.txt", "r") as myInput:
    for line in [l.strip() for l in myInput.readlines()]:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            myList.append(line)

# Get all lines with more than one word
more_than_one = list(compress(myList, [len(e.strip().split(" "))>1 for e in myList]))
# Get all lines with only one word
only_one_word = list(compress(myList, [len(e.strip().split(" "))==1 for e in myList]))
# Keep only unique set of initial words of more_than_one
unique_first_words = list(set([e.split(" ")[0] for e in more_than_one]))
# Remove all union set words from only_one_word
only_one_word_reduced = [e for e in only_one_word if e not in unique_first_words]
# Combine more_than_one and only_one_word_reduced
combined_list = only_one_word_reduced + more_than_one
```

Do you have any suggestions on making the Python code slimmer and more straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, the lines don't need to be kept in order.

This code reads each line of the file once. If there are multiple words  on a line, it is appended to `combined_lines` and the first words is added to a set of first words.  Another set is used for single words. At the end, any single words that aren't a first word (using set subtraction) are added to `combined_lines`.

With revisions suggested in the comments:

```
combined_lines = list()
single_words = set()
first_words = set()

with open("myInput.txt", "r") as sourcefile:
    for line in sourcefile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '' or line.startswith("#"):
            continue

        first, rest = line.split(maxsplit=1)

        if rest:
            combined_lines.append(line)
            first_words.add(first)

        else:
            single_words.add(first)

    combined_lines.extend(single_words - first_words)
```

Comment: FYI `lines` is not defined.

Comment: Also, you're going to want to pass `maxsplit` since you only care about the first token. Doing so will avoid your need for a `*` so will be marginally faster.

Comment: @RootTwo Thanks for the explanations. Understanding that the last line should rather be `combined_lines.extend(single_words - first_words)`, this is indeed a much more Pythonic way of approaching the problem than I had.

Answer (score 2):

```py
# Get all lines with more than one word
more_than_one = list(compress(myList, [len(e.strip().split(" "))>1 for e in myList]))
```

- The function `split` splits by whitespaces by default, there is no need to pass the explicit argument
- Lines have been stripped already when reading the file, using `strip` seems unnecessary
- Using list comprehension should be enough, without the function `compress` and `list`

For example:

```py
more_than_one = [line for line in myList if len(line.split()) > 1]
```

Or:

```py
more_than_one = [line for line in myList if ' ' in line]
```

- Same observations for `Get all lines with only one word`

---

```py
# Keep only unique set of initial words of more_than_one
unique_first_words = list(set([e.split(" ")[0] for e in more_than_one]))
```

- Not sure why the `set` is converted to a `list`. Checking for unique words in a set is much faster than in a list

---

- **Functions**: would be better to include all the operations in a function, for easier testing and reuse
- **PEP 8**: function and variable names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. `myList` should be `my_list`. [More info](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

---

A function that does the same could be the following:

```
def remove_duplicates(lines):
    seen = set()
    for line in lines:
        first_word, *tail = line.split()
        if tail:
            seen.add(first_word)
    return [line for line in lines if line not in seen]
```

An use it like:

```
print(remove_duplicates(['a','a b','b','c','c d','z']))
# Output: ['a b', 'b', 'c d', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you have several useful suggestions already, they don't quite cut to
the heart of the matter. Your example fits into a common type of problem: read
a text file; parse it to extract information; perform some computations on that
information; and report to the user. In my experience one of the best things
you can do to keep this type of code fairly simple and easy to maintain is to
**convert to meaningful information early in the process**. Here's one way to
do that for your use case:

```
# Use fileinput, so we don't have to hard code the file
# path in the script. This is handy for development/debugging.

import fileinput

# Define a meaningful object to hold information about each line.
# You could use a namedtuple, a dataclass, or an attrs class.

from collections import namedtuple

WordLine = namedtuple('WordLine', 'line first rest')

# Convert the raw information (lines) to those meaningful objects.

wlines = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    first, *rest = line.split()
    wlines.append(WordLine(line, first, rest))
```

From that point forward, the algorithmic computations become so simple that
they don't amount to much. A few examples:

```
more_than_one = [wl for wl in wlines if wl.rest]
only_one_word = [wl for wl in wlines if not wl.rest]
unique_first_words = set(wl.first for wl in wlines)
```

Comment: +1. Instead of `words = line.split()`, I find the assignment `first, *rest = line.split()` to lead to more readable usages later on, since `wlines.append(WordLine(line, words[0], words[1:]))` becomes `wlines.append(WordLine(line, first, rest))`.

Comment: @riskypenguin Yes, that approach is better.